# Configure Spring MVC application to make changes to html files/templates without recompiling

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a very simple Spring 4.0 Boot project. I would like to start the application and be able to make changes to the html files located in `/templates/` on the fly, without having to stop and restart the application. Changes to static assets, like java scripts or css files, is no problem.

Below are the details of my program:

There are no XML configuration files. This class is used for configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MVCConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

          registry.addResourceHandler("assets/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/assets/");
          registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/");
          registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/img/");
          registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/js/");

    }
}
```

This is my controller.

```
@Controller
public class ControlFreak {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I have `index.html` located in `templates/`

I run the application using this class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That kind of flexibility is not a good idea, in the long run. You should regard your HTML templates as code, just like Java. Stopping the application to upgrade it is not onerous.

Comment: I don't need to stop and start the server for html pages using publish with the ide usually takes care of it for me. For the java classes i use jrebel http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: @Michael will [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-static-content) be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is easily done using an IDE and will save a heck of a lot of time during development.

First of all you need to configure Spring Boot to not cache Thymeleaf templates by setting:

`spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`

Then you just need to start the application using the IDE in debug mode (just Debug the class with the `main` method) and whenever you make change to a Thymeleaf Template you just need to instruct the IDE to reload the project.

In IntelliJ IDEA, that is done from the  `Reload Changed Classes` option in the `Run` menu.

I think you can configure Eclipse to automatically update the project on each change, but it's been a while since I have used it.

Answer (score 0):

## Path to project

```
project.base-dir=file:///C:/temp/auth/
```

## Templates reloading during development

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=${project.base-dir}/src/main/resources/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

## Static resources reloading during development

```
spring.resources.static-locations=${project.base-dir}/src/main/resources/static/
spring.resources.cache-period=0
```